# $g ( n ) ∈ ω ( 1 )$ and $f ( n ) ∈ o ( g ( n ) )$ imply $2 f ( n ) ∈ o ( 2 g ( n ) )$

Tags: big-o-notation

> Prove that if $g ( n ) ∈ ω ( 1 )$ and $f ( n ) ∈ o ( g ( n ) )$, then $2 f ( n ) ∈ o ( 2 g ( n ) )$.

I was going over this question in my Algorithms class and could'nt understand why first condition has to be met. How would $g ( n ) ∈ ω ( 1 )$ affect our reasoning? Also, what would happen if instead of $g ( n ) ∈ ω ( 1 )$, it was $g ( n ) ∈ o ( 1 )$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type equations. The first condition is completely redundant. For any $f,g$: $f = o(g) \implies 2f = o(2g)$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering non negative case we have
$$O(f)=\{g: \exists C>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n>N, g(n) \leqslant Cf(n)\}$$
From this definition for $\forall C>0,$ we have:
$$ C \cdot O(f)= O(C \cdot f) = O(f)$$
It can be written also as:
$$C \cdot g \in O(f) \Leftrightarrow g \in O(C \cdot f) \Leftrightarrow g \in O(f)$$
without any additional condition.